# Power Designer 16.6 don't create AUTO_INCREMENT to primary column

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment, powerdesigner

I have a problem with PowerDesigner. It doesn't generate AUTO_INCREMENT option for primary columns.

I have int column with Primary key checked in my table, but in generated script there's no AUTO_INCREMENT. DBMS is Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primary key identifies the row. There are plenty of options apart from auto_increment columns, including composite key, values provided from external systems.

The `Identity` property on the column triggers the generation of the identity keyword in the script.

[image]

Comment: Identity property is checked, but AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't appear in generated script.

Comment: ... because SQL Server uses `identity`instead of `auto_increment`?
create table FOO (BARKEY int **identity**, BARDATA int null, constraint PK_FOO primary key (BARKEY))